# Getting only values from object literal

Tags: javascript

Going on from this question: [Getting first object from javascript litteral](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286159/getting-first-object-from-javascript-litteral)

Would it be possible to get only the values from a group of name:value pairs? So lets say we have a list of objects, each object having any number of values:

```
var items = [
    {name:"Foo", age:16, gender:"m"},
    {name:"Bar", age:17, gender:"f"},
    {name:"foo", age:16, gender:"m"},
    {name:"bar", age:18, gender:"m"},
    {name:"foobar", age:18, gender:"f"},
    {name:"barfoo", age:20, gender:"f"}
];
```

How can I return a list like:

```
var items = [
    ["Foo", 16, "m"],
    ["Bar", 17, "f"],
    ["foo", 16, "m"],
    ["bar", 18, "m"],
    ["foobar", 18, "f"],
    ["barfoo", 20, "f"]
];
```

I have tried this but was wondering if there was a better way of doing it.

```
Array.prototype.getValues = function () {
    if(typeof(this[0]) != typeof({}))
        throw "Array values are expected to be == typeof({})";
    var items = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        var r = [];
        for (var l in this[i]) {
            r.push(this[i][l]);
        }
        items.push(r);
    }
    return items; 
};
```

Comment: I have to ask What have you tried?

Comment: I don't see why this was voted down so much -.-

Comment: No offense, but here on StackOverflow people don't really write code for you, but instead look at your code if you are stuck and tell you what kind of mistakes you made. So if you ask a question, you should normally include what you have tried. I removed my downvote as you included your code.

Comment: Yeah, I usually do post what I have tried. I referenced code that I have already written in my other question. Which was pretty much the same...

Comment: Where as in this one instead of using `if(c == 0) items.push(r[n]); c += 1;`, I tried otherwise, but in the other situation it didn't work so well. So I was wanting to know a better way of doing it for any situation.

Comment: By the way, your code is fine, except the line `items.push(items)`. I guess you wanted to push `r` into `items`. And if the code is actually the same as in your other question (which is simply not true), why did you ask a new question? ;) No offense, btw.

Comment: Was an edit from another piece of code. I always seem to do that one. In my other function I use `items.push({index:this[i][z[0]],value:this[i][z[1]]});` instead so yeah. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var newitems=[];
//loop through each item in the original
for(var i =0; i<items.length; i++)
{
  newitems[i] = [];
  //loop over the properties in each element and push it to an array
  for(var prop in items[i]){
    newitems.push(items[i][prop]);
  }
}
```

or alternatively:

```
var newitems = items.map(function(elem){
  var item = [];
  for(var prop in elem){
    item.push(elem[prop]);
  }
  return item;
})
```

Comment: @SmartLemon `Array.prototype` is definitely not the place for that, since that's a very specific method that does not apply to every array.

Comment: Agreed with @bfavaretto, Array.prototype should only be for things that apply to all arrays.

Comment: I agree, but I need it for a lot of my things. Also it is only in certain files of js, and only that file is used in that page.

Comment: But why not just define a function you can pass an array to?  No need to put it on the prototype